# How to make docker application use port 80 (http) instead of 443 (https)

Tags: apache, http, ssl, nginx, docker

I recently installed [this web application](https://github.com/openseedbox/openseedbox) on my Ubuntu server which runs Apache (SSL disabled).

It doesn't matter how much i try i can't get the application to use http. tried the `-p` flag. Then it exposes port 443 and binds something else. I hate browser warnings about SSL. I just want to use http with port 8080.

The application use nginx which only listens to 443. I want my application URL to look like `http://localhost:8080` This application use Google OAuth for logins. I'm assuming it will work on http.

How to get it to work in http?

Answer (score 2):

You must edit nginx.conf in order to use plain http (nginx will never speak http on a https port, only for some errors)

Change:

```
listen 443;
    server_name localhost;

    access_log /dev/stdout;
    error_log /dev/stderr;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /src/openseedbox/conf/host.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key  /src/openseedbox/conf/host.key;
```

To:

```
listen 8080;
    server_name localhost;

    access_log /dev/stdout;
    error_log /dev/stderr;
```

Then after docker build, run with:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 .......
```

---

Alternatively you can set your Apache as an HTTP virtual host that reverse-proxy to the secure HTTPS nginx. But I think it is easier to modify nginx config.

---

**Approach #2**

You can add another nginx container to act as reverse proxy, not sure if the application behind will break, but it acts as http "plainer":

docker-compose.yml

```
# Add this:
plain_nginx:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./plain_nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    links:
      - openseedbox
```

plain_nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    access_log /dev/stdout;
    error_log /dev/stderr;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
      proxy_pass https://openseedbox;
    }
}
```

Then do from `./docker/` directory in that repo:

```
docker-compose up
```

Then you have `http://localhost:8080` acting as reverse proxy of the SSL stuff

Comment: Tried this. But still the application uses port 443

Comment: I added Approach #2. Let me know if it's ok for you

Comment: Thank you so much for this descriptive answer. So as i understand, if i do this my address will look like that but still it's going to redirect to https or i'm going to end up with a 400 `The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port` error right? Because i tried something like this. Please Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: There won't be such `plain http to https port` because the new nginx reverse-proxy to https port using SSL behind as you can see here `proxy_pass https://openseedbox;`. There can still be some issue if the openseedbox application itself re-check and complains. But please try it, I couldnt because I did not provide the Google IDs and that stuff

Comment: Thank you so much for going into such trouble. I'll try this and will get back to you. BTW How can i edit the images? I did a search and found the port 443 is only mentioned on `docker-compose.yml`, `Dockerfile` as `EXPOSE 443` and the nginx config file. Does this mean that By simply editing these files i can get it to work?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to tell you, I'm a complete noob. So please bear with me :D

Comment: Yes, it does. But that is the first approach I've posted. Using the 2nd you only add a file and a service in docker-compose.yml

Comment: Sure, no problem!

Comment: Hi. I just got it to work by just editing the config.v2.json & hostconfig.json. I also had to edit the nginx.conf and replace it in the containers path using a cp command. Now it works. But there's still a problem. When i click something in the page, it removes the port 8080 from the address. Then apache returns an error. If i add the `:8080` manually, it works.